# Get text from closest DIV contains string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, closest

I'm trying to get the full text of a dynamic id div that contains a string.

For example:

```
<div class="test1">
  <div id="div1"> 
    <div id="div2">
     <div id="div3">
       <p>COD: 123 Status: OK</p>
       <h2>Approved</h2>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

That way works. But only what is inside the p

```
var codigoExame     =   $( "p:contains('OK')").html()
-- returns COD: 123 Status: OK
```

If I use the same way, it returns all content from the parent divs

I need all the content inside the closest div and I tried doing it in the following ways:

```
var a = $(this).closest("div").is(":contains('OK')").text()
    
var b = $(this).parents("div").parents().eq(1).is(":contains('OK')").text()
    
var c = $(this).closest('div').attr('id').is(":contains('OK')")
```

Did not work.

Any ideas on how I can get this content?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The closest to what?  Can you include an example of what you expect the output to be?

Comment: The output that I need is  
<p>COD: 123 Status: OK</p>
<h2>Approved</h2>

Comment: `document.querySelector("#div3").children` or `document.querySelector("#div3").innerHTML`. I am not sure what you want.

Comment: You need to change `.text()` to `.html()` if you want to include the HTML

Comment: I need all content within <div id="div3">

The difference is that this div id is dynamic. In the example it is div3, but in a next reading it could be div88 or div23

Comment: so I am trying to get the div closest to the text to retrieve all this content

Comment: Again, the *closest to what*?  "the text"?  How do you identify which text?  How are you determining `this`?   Is it `p:contains("OK")`?    In which case your line `.closest("div")` `var a = $("p:contains('OK')").closest("div").html()`, change .text to .html and use your selector or `this` if `this` is in the context.   You rarely need a dynamic id, and even rarer need to reference a dynamic one.

Comment: @freedomn-m
Here is an example ...

http://jsfiddle.net/fsco4v0m/

I need all the contents of div2, remembering that this div can be variable.

The search screen uses that wordpress elementor, and some pages, the divs change.

Comment: How are you identifying that you need div2 in your fiddle?   ie you, manually, not via code.  Why not div3?

Comment: There is the problem.
I am not finding a way to do this.

If i search for div, it shows me the whole div structure.

so I was trying to do it with the closest, but I couldn't do it either.

Comment: "search for a div" - what criteria are you using to search?  You don't just "search for a div" and expect to get the 2nd one.  There must be some reason you think the result should be the 2nd div.

Comment: In the fiddle..

var a = $('div:contains("test")').eq(1).css('background-color', 'red');

This is what I need.
I believe there is a better way to do this. 
But this one solves what I need.